# Pytorch FCN SHAP plotting bug

Tags: plot, pytorch, linear-regression, shap

I have a pytorch fcn that takes 76 features and predicts 1 output target. I want to use SHAP to display its summary_plot like in https://www.kaggle.com/code/ceshine/feature-importance-from-a-pytorch-model/notebook . I keep getting an error on a specific line and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've attached my code and commented where the error pops up. [code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLqHZ.jpg) The error is usually about mismatched tensor sizes of 64 and 32 which makes me think it may be from my FCN that goes from size 76-1024-512-256-128-64-32-1. I get
"RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (32) at non-singleton dimension 1".

I've confirmed that train_features and feature_samples are of the same shape, and have played around with different syntax changes that Chat GPT presribed, but none resulted in any success.

I got it to worked by changing my network architecture to go from input size (76) and pass linear layers going from 64 to 64 and finally to 1, but would like it to work with my current architecture because it drops the mean squared error a good bit